# Salvage mp3 files from very old PC

Tags: windows

I have a very old PC that is running Windows 95.  It has a 5 1/4" and a 3.5" disc drive as well as a CD-R drive.  No USB port or ethernet capability.  I have many mp3 files that I would like to salvage. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you feel comfortable removing the hard drive from the machine?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options you can do take:

Remove the old hard drive and do one of the following

1. Put the hard drive in the new machine (assuming the new machine has an IDE connection)
2. OR attach it to a USB to IDE/SATA adapter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HJ99DI) - this is an essential tool for IT

You have a CD-R, can you burn the MP3s to CD and move them?  Or are there just to many of them?  If the computer is so old, I cant imagine the hard drive is that large.  I would suspect they would fit on just a couple CDs

Or you can buy a cheap network card and attach the machine to your network.  There are plenty of cheap [PCI](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=391655&CatId=587) cards out there.  ISA cards are out there, if your machine is *that* old.  Buying ISA cards new is overpriced (they do still [sell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004574AXW) them), however you can probably find one for free out there if you look hard enough.

Comment: I deleted my comment before you replied.  I didn't notice your linked device was both SATA and IDE.

Comment: +1 for "assuming it is IDE/SATA". In computers from the w95 time it  can also be MFM or SCSI. IF it is MFM then the drive and [ISA] controller should be treated as one unit.

Comment: I would genuinely be surprised if it was SCSI.  SCSI was generally for high performance workstations and servers.  Only the "geeks" had SCSI at home back then.  As for MFM, I dont remember seeing MFM controllers on anything past a 286... Not to say it didnt happen tho.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the harddrive from the computer case. There is tons of tutorials on how to do this, of course each case in unique. Here's a pictorial solution that should be enough to get you started.

http://www.fonerbooks.com/r_hard.htm

Secondly, you need a way to attach it to your current PC. You could go the longer, slightly more complicated, but cheaper route and install it into your PC if it has IDE headers to plug into. Or you could simply buy a cheap IDE-to-USB interface and plug it into your machine externally.

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B001OORMVQ/ref=asc_df_B001OORMVQ2370578?smid=A99MZGWBBIGK9&tag=sdcbing91-20&linkCode=asn&creative=395129&creativeASIN=B001OORMVQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001OORMVQ)

Either method will work, just depends if you'd rather spend time, or money.